# What is the ionic2 best practice to show loading, alerts and logs?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm looking for ionic2 best practice to show loadings, alerts and console logs..

so instead of repeat the code below in each page so I can call it once.

For example code to show loading:

```
  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: ''
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
```

Is it the best practice to create a provider, and show the loading from the last? or the provider doesn't support loading or something similar ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually create a lib folder (or module if you want). Then, I create some providers. For alert, you can create a provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Alert {

  constructor(
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {}

  show(title: string, subTitle: string, buttons: Array<string>): void{
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: subTitle,
      buttons: buttons
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Or for loading for example:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Loader {

  loader: any;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {}

  present(msg = `Please wait...`) {
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait..."
    });
    this.loader.present();
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.loader.dismiss();
  }
}
```

And then, You can reuse in any components with module path mapping for example:

```
import { Alert, Toast } from '@lib';
```

Is this a best practice ? Yes, I think. You write less code and yo can reuse your lib providers.

Hope I help!

Comment: You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I usually create an UtilProvider and then I create a method to show a loading dialog, for example:

```
public getLoading(message?) {
    if (!message) {
      message = 'Loading...';
    }
    return this.loadCtrl.create({content: message});
  }
```

You can add the time out or just return the `create`, call `present()` and then `dismiss()` after.

I think that use it to AlertController is not really good, cause you will not handle de buttons click