# Ionic 2: create a single loading or toast object

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am a newbie to Ionic 2 and Typescript, now I want to create a single loading (https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#loading) or toast object to use it everywhere. Because toast or loading object always do the same action so that I do not need to create the same thing in many place. Does anyone have an idea for me ? Thank you so much

Comment: I answer this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191016/what-is-the-ionic2-best-practice-to-show-loading-alerts-and-logs/49191464#49191464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a class where you inject the loading:

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class LoaderClass {
     constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController)

     presentLoading() {
        let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: "Loading..",
          duration: 3000
        });
        loader.present();
     }

}
```

then, inject this class into any where you need to use the loading

```
import { LoaderClass } from '../ubication';

export class anyClass {
    constructor(public loaderClass: LoaderClass)

    presentLoading() { //from the loader class
        this.loaderClass.presentLoading();
    }
}
```